# Google Font API - Text not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, fonts

I'm using Google's Font API for a website and all is well on my machine..I can see every bit of text, but on any computer that isn't mine, the text doesn't even load! We both are using the most up-to-date version of Chrome, and here's the code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700,300|Marck+Script);
```

and

```
body {
  font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

as well as this in the HTML files:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Any ideas on a fix?

**UPDATE:**

I learned that it's the Chrome 33 bug causing the web fonts not to load. My only solution is to load the fonts onto the server.

Comment: Could you upload a working example? I have some theories, you shouldn't have to @import and <link> as long as the linked stylesheet loads before.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `<link>` tag is before the css, and that all the files are on the server as opposed to your local machine.

It works here, http://jsfiddle.net/CSLdF/.

Comment: Here's an update on the conundrum...it works on MY Chrome browser, as well as my other inferior browsers (IE 10, etc.) however, the problem is it doesn't load on my colab partner, nor my mother's Chrome browsers. It loads fine on their IE and FireFox browsers. I found if I go into Chroes debugging thing and disable the font-family tag the text shows, and when re-enabled the text is the propper font and visible.

Now, 1...what's different about mine? I'm not sure. But more importantly, what's happening on the first load that makes it invisible?

Comment: Note: it's not on my local machine...the link is directly to Google Fonts. It loads visible on my partner's machine after a refresh, but not on my mother's until disabled and re-enabled.